# Magento 1.7.0.2 - "Edit Order" blank page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I try to click "edit" on an order in Magento 1.7.0.2, i end up with a blank admin-page. No errors logged and no errors appears when i enable developer-mode.

The URL i end up with is /admin_slug/orders_edit/ (no order id)

[Magento Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGVwE.png)

Have any of you experienced anything like this? And how is this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
$this->_redirect('*/*');
```

To

```
$this->_redirect('*/sales_order_edit');
```

in

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/EditController.php

And now it works..